# DNS fails over time. Reconnecting to wifi solves it momentarily

Tags: network, wifi, dns

The DNS lookup fails after some time of being connected. I can get it back working if i reconnect to my wifi. However it seems to happen more frequently.

I enabled debugging in the mDNS responder to see what happens when the error occurs.

```
21/02/16 16:22:14,721 mDNSResponder[100]: --------------
21/02/16 16:22:14,721 mDNSResponder[100]: -- Sent UDP DNS Query (flags 0100) RCODE: NoErr (0) RD ID: 10907 30 bytes from port 61929 to 8.8.4.4:53    --
21/02/16 16:22:14,721 mDNSResponder[100]:  1 Questions
21/02/16 16:22:14,722 mDNSResponder[100]:  0 skydrive.wns.windows.com. AAAA
21/02/16 16:22:14,722 mDNSResponder[100]:  0 Answers
21/02/16 16:22:14,722 mDNSResponder[100]:  0 Authorities
21/02/16 16:22:14,722 mDNSResponder[100]:  0 Additionals
```

After disconnecting wifi and enabling it again is works again:

```
17/02/16 18:53:52,278 mDNSResponder[30063]:  1 Questions
17/02/16 18:53:52,278 mDNSResponder[30063]:  0 ap.spotify.com. Addr
17/02/16 18:53:52,278 mDNSResponder[30063]:  9 Answers
17/02/16 18:53:52,278 mDNSResponder[30063]:  0 TTL     115   21 ap.spotify.com. CNAME ap.gslb.spotify.com.
17/02/16 18:53:52,278 mDNSResponder[30063]:  1 TTL     115    4 ap.gslb.spotify.com. Addr 194.132.162.248
17/02/16 18:53:52,278 mDNSResponder[30063]:  2 TTL     115    4 ap.gslb.spotify.com. Addr 194.14.177.3
17/02/16 18:53:52,278 mDNSResponder[30063]:  3 TTL     115    4 ap.gslb.spotify.com. Addr 194.132.162.198
17/02/16 18:53:52,278 mDNSResponder[30063]:  4 TTL     115    4 ap.gslb.spotify.com. Addr 194.132.162.18
17/02/16 18:53:52,278 mDNSResponder[30063]:  5 TTL     115    4 ap.gslb.spotify.com. Addr 194.132.162.196
17/02/16 18:53:52,278 mDNSResponder[30063]:  6 TTL     115    4 ap.gslb.spotify.com. Addr 194.132.162.147
17/02/16 18:53:52,278 mDNSResponder[30063]:  7 TTL     115    4 ap.gslb.spotify.com. Addr 194.132.162.3
17/02/16 18:53:52,278 mDNSResponder[30063]:  8 TTL     115    4 ap.gslb.spotify.com. Addr 194.14.177.37
17/02/16 18:53:52,278 mDNSResponder[30063]:  0 Authorities
17/02/16 18:53:52,278 mDNSResponder[30063]:  0 Additionals
17/02/16 18:53:52,278 mDNSResponder[30063]: --------------
```

Have anyone tried anything similar and found a solution?

Edit: sometimes it just starts working again, without reconnecting to wifi.

Hardware: Macbook pro 2015, with dedicated gfx.

Comment: The time stamps on the logs you posted are within 22ms of each other (if I'm reading that right) are you sure you posted the right logs from before and after you reconnected?
Does this happen everywhere or just at your home network?

Comment: Your right, ill update the post next time it happens with correct output when the dns isn't working. It happens mostly when i'm home but it has happen other places.

Comment: What happens when you try a different DNS server?

Comment: It makes no difference. I have tried both my internet provider's and google's. It seems similar to this unsolved problem http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216734/macbook-not-working-with-home-wifi?rq=1